# Average speed question

Tags: homework-and-exercises, speed

Find your average speed if you go 15m/s for 1000 m and then 30m/s for 1000 m

I understand that average speed is total distance / total time. The distance for this problem would be 2000m travelled. How would I figure out the total time?

Answer (score 2):

Try breaking the problem into pieces such that you can figure out the time for each piece.